# Communication between active 3d glasses and monitor?

Tags: display, bluetooth, gaming, 3d, 3d-vision

I know that 3d active shutter glasses work with infared or radio wavew. I know that both of them are harmfull but,

with either of them, the glasses and the source (monitor) communicate one time just to get in sync, or they communicate constantly?

A communication for a second or a couple of seconds is tottaly acceptable, no complains, but constant communication is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contancting a company that makes active shutter glasses and chatting in another forum, they told me that the glasses and the source must communicate constantly because two independent oscilators can never be in sync; even if you synchronize once, they will get out of sync in just a few seconds. In order to do this the monitors and the glasses must have temperature-controled oscilators, which are expensive and big at size.

Answer (score 0):

While there might be a handshake to begin to send, the glasses only need a timing pulse sent to them, there is no need to send information back from the glasses.

Infrared leds of the small size output a tiny bit of infrared,just like a remote control. Bluetooth unlike a cellphone communication is not a very strong radio signal, the design is for very short range operation, so it is a very low power. To get to a cell tower requires much more power. So while i would not discount the existance of an effect, it would be much smaller than many other things.

Comment: "..there is no need to send information back from the glasses.."
So, you mean the just send a handshake only, right?

Comment: mabey an ack, your right bluetooth will always be a computery net interface using packets, which would be acknowledged.  I would need more information on the exact model, there are devices using RF that could be classed as being on a bluetooth frequency without being packet based. there is zero need in this situation for acknolwledge. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth loose streams vis bluetooth?  Using normal BT methods wouldnt make sence when the need is just a very Fast responce pulse.

Comment: Ok. Are u sure about these, or its just a thought/speculation? I cant give you info on any model since I dont have one; I ask this prior to any buy so I know whats going on with the transmitions.

Comment: Nope not sure. try before you buy. the 3d methods still are not perfect.  the best method would be a proper full frame rate full res screen fed to both eyes.  anything less has been gimicky and gives me a headache after a while.  LCD doesnt fully close, polarisation is also not complete, feeding both eyes a half signal awesome to see, but bad to use for a long time.

Comment: You are right on "try before buy", but for the aspects of the glasses. The transmission is surely one of those things that they dont tell you, so in order to know them you have to be an expert and have done some actual tests with a device or something. Thanks for your responce! Hope that someone else might give some insight..